# Angular http - Chain Observables with conditional exits

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-observable

I have a situation where my app needs to fetch some data from the back end and then do several steps of processing with such data. 
What I would implement is something like

```
this.http.get('myurl')
          .map(data => doFirstProcessingStep(data))
          .map(data1 => doSecondProcessingStep(data))
          .map(data2 => doThirdProcessingStep(data))
```

In case though the back-end does not send valid data, I want to exit the processing chain without executing any step and just returning an `Observable.of(null)`

Which is an elegant way to implement such logic?

Comment: if the service returns an error, you should catch. otherwise, consider using filter

Comment: It is not necessary an error. The back end can return an empty set of data. Could you provide more details about how you would apply filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the new `HttpClient`, your response is automagically converted to json. And, if your backend returns an empty response, the `JSON.parse` happening behind the curtains will throw an error.

Within an Observable chain, if an error is thrown, it'll skip every other operators down the chain until it finds a `catch`. So it should definitely work as expected this way:

```
this
  .http
  .get('myurl')
  .map(data => doFirstProcessingStep(data))
  .map(data1 => doSecondProcessingStep(data))
  .map(data2 => doThirdProcessingStep(data))
  .catch(err => Observable.of(null))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
this.http.get('myurl')
    .map(data => this.doAllProcessing(data));

doAllProcessing(data) {
    if (!dataIsValid(data)) {
        return null;
    }
    data = doFirstProcessingStep(data);
    data = doSecondProcessingStep(data);
    data = doThirdProcessingStep(data);

    return data;
}
```